# spring-mvc : issue in accessing url pattern configured in web.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have tested like default, extension, path(start with `'/'` and end with `'/*'`) these three are working fine but exact match url pattern `'/test'` showing 404 error.Please refer this is my exact code in web.xml file for configuring dispatcher servlet.

```xml
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>frontController</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>frontController</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
```

For this url on address bar :http://localhost:8086/MVCFirstApp/test/sugar

I am getting error - `404 page not found` for exact match url pattern only.

Please help me out from this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have servlet for mapping `/test/sugar` ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check few steps before reading the solutions
+ do you have proper controller to handle the requested request(url pattern)
+ do you have proper view returned by the controller 
+ and is the base package scanned for controller (annotations)

It would be more convenient if you share the controller code too.  But with what I understand with your statement you can try this 
add URL patters as 
    /test/*

Let me explain what this does it will send all the request which comes tru URL /test/ to dispatcher servlet .  For example  /test/sugar or /test/abc/def/ghi anything,  in more simple words any request with URL /test/* is sent to dispatcher servlet which matches and return the proper controller with help of handler mapping .

And make sure you have added the mapping for /test/sugar or /test with proper view in controller .  Or if you want sugar to be your value then use  @Pathvariable in your controller.